# How to force IE to place two div boxes next to each other in it's browser window?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, internet-explorer

I have done a  very basic layout for my website. Now the site gets displayed perfect in Chrome, Mozila and Opera as it should be.

*But only remaining problem is with IE. Since I have two boxes which sits next to each other in my browser window, the IE just breaks them and place one below another, what I definitely don't want.*

**How to get rid of this trouble?**

[NOTE: I haven't published my site in webserver yet. I am just running it in my localhost]

The following is my complete code:

.PHP:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>My site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>



<body>

<div id="big_wrapper">

<header id="top_header">
<h1>My site</h1>


</header>

<nav id="top_menu">
<ul>
<li>Opening Hours</li>
<li>Registration</li>
</ul>

</nav>
<div id="new_div">
<section id="main_section">



<article>


<hgroup>
<header>
<h1>Title of article1</h1>
<h2>subTitle of article1</h2>

</header>
</hgroup>



<p>This is a best aricle1</p>

<footer>

<p> Written by...1</p>
</footer>

</article>


<article>


<hgroup>
<header>
<h1>Title of article2</h1>
<h2>subTitle of article2</h2>

</header>
</hgroup>



<p>This is a best aricle2</p>

<footer>

<p> Written by...2</p>
</footer>

</article>


</section>

<aside id="side_news">


<h4>News</h4>
Put your news

</aside>
</div>

<footer id="the_footer">


Put your footer

</footer>

</div>

</body>


</html>
```

.CSS:

```
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
h1{

font:bold 20px Tahoma;
}
h2{

font:bold 14px Tahoma;
}
header,section,footer,aside,nav,article,hgroup{
display:block;

}
body{
width:100%;
display:-webkit-box;
display:-moz-box;
display:-ms-box;
box-pack:center;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
-moz-box-pack:center;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
-ms-box-pack:center;
/*
text-align:center;
*/
}


#big_wrapper{
max-width:1200px;
margin-top:20px;


display:-webkit-box;
display:-moz-box;
display:-ms-box;
box-orient:vertical;
-webkit-box-orient:vertical;
-moz-box-orient:vertical;
-ms-box-orient:vertical;
box-flex:1;
-webkit-box-flex:1;
-moz-box-flex:1;
-ms-box-flex:1;


}
#top_header{
background:yellow;
border:3px soild gray;
padding:20px;

}
#top_menu{
border:green;
background:gray;
color:white;
}
#top_menu li{
display:inline-block;
list-style:none;
padding:5px;
font:bold 14px Tahoma;

}

#new_div{
display:-webkit-box;
display:-moz-box;
display:-ms-box;
box-orient:horizontal;
-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
-moz-box-orient:horizontal;
-ms-box-orient:horizontal;

}

#main_section{
border:1px solid blue;
box-flex: 1;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-moz-box-flex: 1;
-ms-box-flex: 1;

margin:20px;
padding:20px;


}

#side_news{
border:1px solid blue;
width:220px;

margin:20px 0px;
padding:30px;
background:#66CCCC;

}

#the_footer{

text-align:center;

padding:20px;
border-top:2px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the float of the boxes and the `display` status

Try this, it should work fine..
http://jsfiddle.net/4sdvk8gL/

```
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
h1{

font:bold 20px Tahoma;
}
h2{

font:bold 14px Tahoma;
}
header,section,footer,aside,nav,article,hgroup{
display:block;

}
body{
width:100%;
display:-webkit-box;
display:-moz-box;
display:-ms-box;
box-pack:center;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
-moz-box-pack:center;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
-ms-box-pack:center;
/*
text-align:center;
*/
}


#big_wrapper{
max-width:1200px;
margin-top:20px;


display:-webkit-box;
display:-moz-box;
display:-ms-box;
box-orient:vertical;
-webkit-box-orient:vertical;
-moz-box-orient:vertical;
-ms-box-orient:vertical;
box-flex:1;
-webkit-box-flex:1;
-moz-box-flex:1;
-ms-box-flex:1;


}
#top_header{
background:yellow;
border:3px soild gray;
padding:20px;

}
#top_menu{
border:green;
background:gray;
color:white;
}
#top_menu li{
display:inline-block;
list-style:none;
padding:5px;
font:bold 14px Tahoma;f

}

#new_div{
display:block;
display:-moz-box;
display:-ms-box;
box-orient:horizontal;
-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
-moz-box-orient:horizontal;
-ms-box-orient:horizontal;

}

#main_section{
border: 1px solid blue;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-moz-box-flex: 1;
-ms-box-flex: 1;
margin: 20px;
padding: 20px;
float: left;
width: calc(75% - 82px);


}

#side_news{
border: 1px solid blue;
width: 220px;
margin: 20px 0px;
padding: 30px;
background: #66CCCC;
float: left;
display: block;
width: calc(25% - 62px);

}

#the_footer{

text-align:center;

padding:20px;
border-top:2px solid green;
}
```